# Solr stores map instead of atomic update

Tags: solr, atomic

When trying to perform an atomic update of "fields", I end up with a map stored there (like 'add=something') instead of its atomic add operation. The field is stored, docValues and multiValued. Can't get: what I'm doing wrong?

```
    ...
    final SolrQuery query = new SolrQuery("tag:(" + term + ')');

    final AddUpdateCommand addUpdateCommand;
    final SolrQueryRequest queryRequest = new LocalSolrQueryRequest(targetCore, query)
    addUpdateCommand = new AddUpdateCommand(queryRequest);

    final SolrInputDocument document = new SolrInputDocument();
    document.addField("tag", term);
    document.addField("fields", ImmutableMap.of("add", fieldName));

    addUpdateCommand.solrDoc = document;
    assert AtomicUpdateDocumentMerger.isAtomicUpdate(addUpdateCommand);

    updateHandler.addDoc(addUpdateCommand);
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up with simply storing a `List` instead of `Map`, manually updating the contents of necessary fields. By some reason atomic updates do not work.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
Map<String,Object> fieldModifier = new HashMap<>(1);
fieldModifier.put("add",fieldName);
sdoc.addField("fields", fieldModifier);  // add the map as the field value
```

Comment: Means, I can't use ImmutableMap? Otherwise, it looks there is no difference except I inlined it.

Comment: yeah, try declaring the map explicitly as Map<String,Object>, otherwise maybe code is not going though the update path